# Assistance stubbing a function inside class

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon

I am trying to stub Enmap's set method. This is my function (inside of my `Queue` class):

```
// save queue for persistence
  save() {
    enmap.set('queue', this._queue);
}
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
var enmapStub;
  beforeEach(() => {
    enmapStub = sinon.stub(new enmap(), 'set');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    enmapStub.restore();
  });
```

Then using it in my test:

```
describe('#save', () => {
    it("calls enmap.set", () => {
      new Queue({ queueName: 'test', queue: [1,2,3] }).save();
      expect(enmapStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    });
  });
```

The test fails because enmapStub has not been called?

I am new to using `sinon` and mocking in general so I'm sure I missed a step or something. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: can you try defining the scope as `this.enmapStub`? I've worked with that kind of global object and it worked. This way, you won't need to define it globally.

Comment: I did that and it made no difference in the test results, still didn't call the stub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined the issue, as I wanted to mock the set method of another class (`Enmap`) I needed to stub the prototype of Enmap like so:

```
this.enmapStub;
beforeEach(() => {
  this.enmapStub = sinon.stub(enmap.prototype, 'set');
});

afterEach(() => {
  this.enmapStub.restore();
});
```

stubbing the prototype instead of the instance of Enmap works much better.